# Авторизация на hh.ru

Tags: python, python-3.x

У меня есть код который не может найти войти в аккаунт. Выдает ошибку 404, хотя такая страница есть.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs


url = "https://hh.ru/account/login?backurl=%2F.php"
session = requests.Session()
headers = {
    "accept": "*/*",
    "user-agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1; rv:47.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/47.0"
}

request = session.get(url, headers=headers)
login_data = {
    'username': '***@mail.ru',
    'password': '********',
    'remember': 'yes',
    '_xsrf': 'not'
}

soup = bs(request.text, "lxml")
login_data['_xsrf'] = soup.find('input', attrs={"name": "_xsrf", })['value']

def authorize(login, passw):
    post = requests.post(
        'https://belgorod.hh.ru/account/login?backurl=/',
        data={
            'backUrl': 'https://belgorod.hh.ru/',
            'failUrl': r'/account/login?backurl=%2F',
            'username': login,
            'password': passw,
            'remember': 'yes',
            '_xsrf': login_data['_xsrf']
        },
        allow_redirects=False
    )
    return post


auth = authorize("***@mail.ru", "***")
print(auth)
```

Comment: Этот код не может ничего выдавать.

Comment: Почему? Из-за того что принта нет?

Comment: Добавь в заголовки еще User-agent, без него hh ругается

Comment: + для авторизации на  hh нужен токен: https://dev.hh.ru/admin

Comment: Мне надо через requests

Comment: @JlecHou6paT потому что он ничего не делает. В вашем коде импортируется модуль `requests`, объявляется строковая переменная `url`, создаётся объект `Session` и объявляется словарь. Всё.

Comment: Обновил код. Выдает ошибку 404

Answer (score 1):

url = "https://hh.ru/account/login?backurl=%2F.php" неправильный. Там без ".php"

Comment: Это url возврата, особо не влияет ни на что.

Comment: Нет, вы таким образом пытаетесь получить xsrf. Вам в ответ на запрос по данному url приходит пустое тело ответа. Сделайте запрос без .php и увидите разницу. Вам придет ответ с токеном.